# Invocable Apex IconName Static Resource with full background

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, apexactionfunction

So I've finally had some success getting a custom static resource icon to display on my apex-action component in my flow, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the background color 100% without this apparent padding (see image). Any advice about how to create this SVG icons to ensure consistent results. Ideally I would just provide my icon without a background color similar to using a SLDS icon. In both cases (static or SLDS) I would like to know how to control the background color.

[image]

Hopefully my question here makes sense, basically just want to create custom icons without changing the look and feel too dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be impossible to remove the border here. I tried making the viewBox bigger (e.g. 48x48->64x64), overflowing the container (-20,-20 through 104,104), and so on. I suppose this is done to distinguish custom icons from standard icons, but for now, you'll have to either use slds standard icons, or you'll have to accept the white border. In the interim, you may as well post an idea on the [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search).